# Client Side Custom Validation isn't executing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation

I'm currently in the process of learning ASP.NET 4.0 with c#. I have spent roughly 2 hours researching this issue and I don't currently have a high enough understanding of how it all works to apply it to my own situation so I require 1 on 1 assistance please. Also It's also very likely that my error is very amateur so please don't be afraid to explore that possibility. Finally, thank you for your input

I have made a very basic form that just takes text input for a number of fields (name, email, confirm email, home phone, business phone.) with validation on all fields. All of my validation works except I can't seem to figure out why my client side javascript custom validation (which is simply a requirement that either the home phone field or the business phone field has input) doesn't do anything. Server-side validation works fine (I get the desired results if I post to the server with every other field correct but the custom validation doesn't do anything if one or more other fields are invalid.)

I will try and post all relevant code needed to troubleshoot:
My javascript that sets if the validation is valid if either textbox's have text

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidatePhoneNumbers(source, args)
    {
        var phoneHome = document.getElementById('<%= PhoneHome.ClientID %>');
        var phoneBusiness = document.getElementById('<%= PhoneBusiness.ClientID %>');
        if (phoneHome.value != '' || phoneBusiness != '')
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }   
    }
</script>
```

This is my custom validation mark up:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                ClientValidationFunction="ValidatePhoneNumbers" CssClass="ErrorMessage" 
                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter Your home or business phone number" 
                onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Finally these are my two textboxes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PhoneHome" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="PhoneBusiness" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Have you included the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file in your project? This is the library that usually handles the client-side validation in .net. See this [post](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/using-unobstructive-validation-in-asp.net-4.5-web-forms.htm) about using it in a web forms project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small mistake in your Javascript function, which causes the validation to always succeed:

```
if (phoneHome.value != '' || phoneBusiness != '')
```

should be replaced by:

```
if (phoneHome.value != '' || phoneBusiness.value != '')
```

Comment: Thank so much, its incredibly frustrating that that is what the mistake was but regardless, thank you for pointing it out to me